# Remove a key from an array by its value in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database design mockup

```
<project>
-- data
---- employee
------ employee1
-------- colleagues
---------- 0: employee2_id
---------- 1: employee3_id
---------- 2: employee4_id
---------- 3: employee5_id
```

Goal:
I want to search colleagues array by a value (e.g. employee3_id) and then remove that entry. If I can reorder the list (0,1,2...) it would be even better.

Desired output when I want to remove employee3_id from employee1's colleagues list.

```
<project>
-- data
---- employee
------ employee1
-------- colleagues
---------- 0: employee2_id
---------- 1: employee4_id
---------- 2: employee5_id
```

Code I've so far

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database();
const childRef = databaseRef.ref('data/employee/employee1/colleagues');

let item = 'employee3_id';
let itemList = [];

let itemPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    childRef.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        itemList = snapshot.val();
        resolve(itemList);
    })
});

itemPromise.then(function (itemList) {
    itemList.splice(itemList.indexOf(item), 1);
    childRef.set(itemList);
});
```

Issue so far:
itemList remains empty after **itemList = snapshot.val();** line executes and the whole project gets emptied out.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to fetch data only once, use [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead of `on()`.  `on()` sets up a persistent listener that triggers repeatedly when there is a data change anywhere under the reference location, and it continues to trigger until you remove the listener.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you want here.

Second, both `once()` and `on()` are asynchronous, meaning they return immediately, and the callback function you passed to it is executed some time later.  You don't know how long it will take.  This means that your code will continue executing after `once()` or `on()` without knowing the result of the query.  This is why your `itemList` is empty - that's the value you originally assigned to it, and it hasn't changed yet.

If you want to do something with the results of a query, you should do it in the callback function itself, or make use of the promise returned by `once()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for differentiating once() and on(). As you might have guessed, I'm pretty new to JS, let alone FB. Can you please elaborate on "do it in the callback fx itself or make use of the promise returned by once()?" I've heard about promises but haven't really dived deep enough to understand what it is and how to implement it. Thanks again

Comment: This isn't really the place to explain promises.  You should search that topic to learn about it.  It's pretty foundational to JavaScript programming.  The callback I'm referring to is the function you passed to on() or once().

Comment: Ok, I did some research and updated the code a bit. I think I've promise almost working. Can you please tell me what I'm missing?